# UITableView calling wrong DataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a **Master-Detail-Application**, which uses one `DetailViewController` and multiple TableViewDataSources. Every time the user touches an item, i check the items class and choose the right TableSource for it. 
Just like this:

```
if ([_detailItem isKindOfClass: [cAdress class]]) {
    self.dataSource = [[AddressDetailTableSource alloc] init];
    ((AddressDetailTableSource *) dataSource).current = _detailItem;
} else if ([_detailItem isKindOfClass: [cActivities class]]) {
    self.dataSource = [[ActivityDetailTableSource alloc] init];
    ((ActivityDetailTableSource *) dataSource).current = _detailItem;
}...
```

Sometimes i go more into Detail and push a new `DetailView` above the current `DetailView`. I do this a lot with some different views. Choosing an item in the MasterView causes, that the application goes back to the first DetailView (`popToRootViewController`). 
I now have a problem with one view in particular. When this view is on Top and i choose an item in the `MasterView`, my App crashes. With `NSZombies` i found out, that it still tries to build the table with the wrong DataSource. Or at least it tries to call "`titleForHeaderInSection`" on the wrong DataSource. The error message is:

```
[ItemDetailTableSource tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:]:message sent to deallocated instance...
```

The error only occurs with this specific TableSource, also i treat same all the same.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: better to use a separate view class, and add tableview over that view and set delegates, datasource on that view class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is trying to access datasource using deallocated instance, you better have individual classes for each tableView, it will simplify your work, always try to modulize the classes instead of trying to put everything in just one class.

Comment: What do you mean with "individual classes". Individual DetailViewControllers for every TableView/DataSource?